# Linking few checkboxes to get result of something

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I want to make an app that create a result from few determinants. Like we have three methods with checkboxes and from each we take one, then we get a result of choosing them. For example from first row take lazy, from next computer and for a result you get that you need an office job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented using Android ListView with array-adapter.
You can start by creating pojo's as per you needs . For example you can create following two classes for your specific need that i can figure out from the question

```
    Class Qualities { 
        private int id;
        private string QualityName;
        ...

        getId(){...}
        setId(int id){...}
        getQualityName(){}
        //etc get and set methods

    //toString
    public String toString(){
      return getId()+" "+getQualityName();
    }
  }

     Class Intrests{
        private int id;
        private String InterestName;

        ...
        // all get and set methods
        ....

    //toString
    public String toString(){
      return getId()+" "+getIntrestName();
    }
  }
```

You will use these classes to bind to your list views.For simplicity here I have implemented toString method so that we can attach it to the arrayAdapter easily.Other wise you will have to create a custom layout and create another class that will extend ArrayAdapter and override its methods.
Now create UI with two ListViews- one for your Qualities and other for Interests something like below

[image]

Now in you activity code populate two list views with arrayAdapter

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
....
initListViews();
}

private void initListViews() {

        // create items
        //List view 1
        Qualities q1= new Qualities(1,"Lazy");
        Qualities q2= new Qualities(2,"Hard working");
        Qualities q3= new Qualities(3,"Witty");

        Qualities [] qualities= new Qualities[]{q1,q2,q3};
        // Array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Qualities> adapter1= new ArrayAdapter<Qualities>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,qualities);
        this.listView.setAdapter(adapter1);

        //list view 2
        Intrests i1= new Intrests(1,"Computer");
        Intrests i2= new Intrests(2,"Sports");
        Intrests i3= new Intrests(3,"Commerce");

        Intrests[] interests = new Intrests[]{i1,i2,i3};
        // Array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Intrests> adapter2= new ArrayAdapter<Intrests>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,interests);
        this.listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
```

This way you will get two of the list views with the values that you enter in the array.
Now I am using a button to process the results for simplicity.

```
button_result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               processResult();
           }

       });
```

where processResult() is the method that gives you the selected values from the listviews(objects of Qualities and Interests resp.)

```
private void processResult() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Result button clicked");

        int pos1= listView.getCheckedItemPosition();
        int pos2 = listView2.getCheckedItemPosition();

        Qualities qSelected= (Qualities) listView.getItemAtPosition(pos1);
        Intrests iSelected=(Intrests) listView2.getItemAtPosition(pos2);
        if(qSelected!=null && iSelected!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"result "+ qSelected.getQualityName()+" : "+ iSelected.getInterestName());

            String iAmDoingThis =tellMeWhatShouldIDo(qSelected,iSelected);

            Toast.makeText(this,iAmDoingThis,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Select Something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The below tellMeWhatShouldIDo() implements simple logic to cater your need , you will have to improvise this method to actually suit your need.

```
    private String  tellMeWhatShouldIDo(Qualities q,Intrests i){
            String doThis="";
            if(q.getQualityName().equalsIgnoreCase("lazy") && i.getInterestName().equalsIgnoreCase("computer")){
                doThis="You should do office job";
            }
            else if(q.getQualityName().equalsIgnoreCase("hard working") && i.getInterestName().equalsIgnoreCase("sports")){
                doThis="You should play football";
            }
///..... generalize here to other cases
///
            else{
                doThis="Chill and relax";
            }
            return  doThis;
        }
```

And that's it. Hope this helps.
PS. I havent handled NullPointerException in this code for simplicity.